# binary Tree: printing the data in ascending order

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am a beginner in java .. I have just started the data structure online. 
I want to print the values i have added to the binary tree in ascending order.

I have created a method print and tried it with these values:

> 9,5,2,8,3

It printed this output and stopped

> 2 , 3 ,8

the Nodes have to constructors :

> Constructor 1

```
public Node(int value){
    this.Value=value;
    isEmpty=false;
    this.left=new Node();
    this.right=new Node();
}
```

> Constructor 2

```
public Node(){
   isEmpty=true; 
}
```

> The Adding method :

```
public void add(int value) {

    if (Objects.isNull(root)) {
        root = new Node(value);
        root.isEmpty = false;
    }
    Node current = root;
    while (true) {

        if (value < current.Value) {
            if (current.left.isEmpty) {
                current.left.prev = current;
                current = current.left;
                current.Value = value;
                current.isEmpty = false;
                current.left = new Node();
                current.right = new Node();
                break;
            } else {
                current = current.left;

            }
        } else {
            if (current.right.isEmpty) {
                current.right.prev = current;
                current = current.right;
                current.Value = value;
                current.isEmpty = false;
                current.left = new Node();
                current.right = new Node();
                break;
            } else {
                current = current.right;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

> The Print method

```
ArrayList<Node> list = new ArrayList();
Node current = root;while(true){
 if(!current.left.isEmpty ){
     if(!list.contains(current.left)){
     current=current.left;
     continue;
     }

 } else {
     System.out.println(current.Value);
     list.add(current);
     if(!current.right.isEmpty && !list.contains(current.right)){
       current=current.right;
       continue;
     }

     current=current.prev.prev;
 }
```

Comment: You should do an inorder traversal and print data in order. Also make sure you tree is BST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print data from BST you need to do inorder traversal. In case of binary search trees (BST), Inorder traversal gives nodes in non-decreasing order. To get nodes of BST in non-increasing order, a variation of Inorder traversal where Inorder traversal s reversed can be used.

> Algorithm Inorder(tree)
>      1. Traverse the left subtree, i.e., call Inorder(left-subtree)
>      2. Visit the root.
>      3. Traverse the right subtree, i.e., call Inorder(right-subtree)

```
/* Given a binary tree, print its nodes in inorder*/
void printInorder(Node node) 
{ 
    if (node == null) 
        return; 

    /* first recur on left child */
    printInorder(node.left); 

    /* then print the data of node */
    if(!node.isEmpty){
        System.out.print(node.value+ " "); 
    }

    /* now recur on right child */
    printInorder(node.right); 
}
```

**Time Complexity: O(n)**

---

---

If the tree is not BST. You can create List and write the tree's values into the list and sort the list in ascending order.

```
List<Integer> treeValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();

List<Integer> treeToList(Node node){
    if (node == null) 
        return; 
    printInorder(node.left); 
    if(!node.isEmpty){
        treeValues.add(node.value); 
    }
    printInorder(node.right); 
}

void sortedTree(Node node){
    List<Integer> treeData = treeToList(node);
    Collections.sort(treeData);
    for(int i=0; i<treeData.size();i++ ){
        System.out.println(treeData.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: that's great but there is an issue it will print each node twice i think

Comment: This is correct for normal in-order traversal, but one more thing is needed for OP's tree, which has empty leaf nodes that shouldn't be printed. It should check `node.isEmpty` before printing, and only print if the node is not empty. Also, the value was called `Value`, not `key`.

Comment: @MhdGhd it is not printing twice. You can check it, in case the tree is not a binary search tree, you can make traversal (Inorder, Preorder, Postorder) and write data into the list, then sort the list.

Comment: @DavidConrad thanks for the comment, I made changes.

Comment: @lolo thanks alot it worked but it has a small issue it prints the root twice just the root the rest are perfect

Comment: @MhdGhd printInOrder(x) upon returning prints the value of x exactly once. Yes it starts other calls to itself (namely printInOrder(x.left) and printInOrder(x.right)) but as for printing it only prints x, and only once. If the root was printed twice as you say then that means there were two printInOrder(root) calls somewhere which there are not. This call is only made at the very beginning once. Thus you should see only one print of root. Small disclaimer: haven't myself run this code just looked at it.